# Best way to implement Google Cards style

Tags: android

I'd like to implement a card style to my app to match the Google apps style. What's the best approach to doing this? Would the card be a custom UIElement, or would it just a a xml layout?

Comment: Can you link "google card style" - what exactly that is.

Comment: http://searchengineland.com/figz/wp-content/seloads/2013/04/munich-300x457.png That's the styling.

Answer (score 1):

[Here](https://github.com/gabrielemariotti/cardslib) you have a nice library provided by Gabriele Mariotti.

This is the new library, however it provides features like:

- different parts as a Header, a Thumbnail, a Shadow, a MainContentArea where you can inflate your custom layout
- You can customize the global layout as you like
- You can have some built-in features as OnClickListener, OnSwipeListener , OnLongClickListener
- CardHeader provides an overflow button with a PopupMenuListener, a button to expand/collapse an area, or a customizable button with its listener.
- CardThumbnail load a Bitmap with a resource ID or with a URL using LRUCache and an AsyncTask
- It requires API 14+

If the API 14 isn't a constraint, you can successfully include this lib to your project.

Answer (score 0):

Check [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Tase7wn6ibo) out, it might help you get started...

Comment: Thanks, I can't watch videos at work (YouTube's blocked) but I'll give that a watch when I get home.

Comment: you can also use -

http://theopentutorials.com/tutorials/android/listview/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text-using-baseadapter/

if it helped you, you can accept and vote up =)

Comment: I've just found this http://shardulprabhu.blogspot.in/2012/09/google-now-cards-layout.html which seems to be what I'm after.